# Xcode completition not working across multiple source files

Tags: swift, xcode, autocomplete

I simplify the issue.
I have 2 swift files.

The first one holds the struct definition.
The second holds the the struct declaration.

```
// swift file 1
// definition of struct

import Foundation

struct river {
    var color = ""
    var depth = 0
}
```

When I use this struct in swift file 2 to declare a constant (`tiber`), I do see the struct `S` `river` suggested by the completition feature of Xcode, however the completition doesn't show me the variables (`color` and `depth`) when I type `(` after `river`.

Basically, I have to enter manually the variables for the struct declaration.

```
// swift file 2
// declaration of struct

import Foundation

let tiber = river(color: "blue", depth: 15) // "color: "blue", depth: 15" manually typed
```

Now, when I use `river` a second time, the completition works fine for the variables.

```
// swift file 2
// declaration of struct

import Foundation

let tiber = river(color: "blue", depth: 15) // "color:, depth: " manually typed
let nile = river(color: "green", depth: 11) // "color:, depth: " was suggested properly by completition
```

What goes wrong here?

Also, when struct definition and declaration reside inside the same file, the completition works fine!

I have some quite extensive structs where I would definitely like to have the completition work properly.

I read some postings that deleting the folder `DerivedData` might help. However I don't want to dive that far inside the file system. macOS and Xcode are a fresh installs.

Comment: Welcome to the frustrating world of xcode... I think if you add an explicit initializer for the struct, it works.

Comment: Make sure your xcode is not doing any pre building activities which are still updating the indexes. The auto complete is working for the second time because, it s reading from recently used info than Xcode's intelligence abt the code. Try clean and build. if none of these works, try deleting DerivedData

Comment: I always type `.init`, let the autocomplete, and then remove the optional `.init`. It's quite annoying, I admit.

Comment: @Larme, do you mean you (1.) add a line like `var _ = river.init()` (e.g. just before using the `river()` struct) to the main code, or (2.) an explicit `init()` function inside the struct. I tested both. They both work. Strange that (2.) works though. Seems that a "manual" init() is not doing the same stuff as the "automatic" init() ?!

Comment: I write `.init(` (or less characters from that until XCode show the me suggestions of autocomplete) and select from the autocompletion. It gives me the full `init(color: #placeholder, depth: #placeholder)` method, I replace the place holders, and once I wrote the line, I remove manually the `.init` word (which is optional).

Comment: @Larme, that's what I understood first, but didn't work. Now I tried it again and it works indeed exactly as you described! Tanks !!! (oh man - you need to know this!)

Comment: Ah indeed, it seems that maybe the first time when there is no "explicit init" method it doesn't suggest it. Since I don't give attention to it, that maybe the case. I just do it for all the cases after the first one :p